# Como alterar esse código PHP 5.3 para PHP 5.4?

Tags: php

Como posso alterar o código abaixo para que funcione nas versões 5.3 e 5.4 do PHP? Atualmente só funciona na versão 5.3.

Estou tendo o seguinte erro:

> Strict Standards: Only variables should be passed by reference in
>   /home/public_html/admin/adicionador.php on line 1

```
$arquivo_renomeado = strtolower(end(explode('.', $nome_do_arquivo_original_alterado)));
if ($arquivo_renomeado == 'jpg' || $arquivo_renomeado == 'jpeg') {
    $nome_final = str_replace($nome_do_arquivo_original_alterado,' ',$nome_da_imagem_alterada.'.jpg');
} else if ($arquivo_renomeado == 'png') {
    $nome_final = str_replace($nome_do_arquivo_original_alterado,' ',$nome_da_imagem_alterada.'.png');
# Only if your version of GD includes GIF support
} else if ($arquivo_renomeado == 'gif') {
    $nome_final = str_replace($nome_do_arquivo_original_alterado,' ',$nome_da_imagem_alterada.'.gif');
}
```

Comment: Tem certeza que é nesse local mesmo que o erro é exibido? Olhando rapidamente não notei nada.

Comment: Verifique se na linha acima do erro não esta faltando nada.

Comment: Sim fica dando erro em $arquivo_renomeado = strtolower(end(explode('.', $nome_do_arquivo_original_alterado)));

Comment: Edite a pergunta e adicione a mensagem de erro. O código não parece usar nenhuma função depreciada ou descontinuada.

Comment: Pronto fica aparecendo o erro que esta na edição em negrito acima. Sera que e restrição Host que estou hospedando o site ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O erro diz que você é obrigado a passar uma variável(referência) para função end, não é possivel passar o retorno de uma função/método. Para corrigir crie uma variável intermediaria que recebe o array de [explode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php), depois passe ela para [end()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.end.php).

Fique atento ao olhar o manual do php boa parte das funções que possuem `&`(e comercial) indicam que o parâmetro deve ser uma variável e não uma valor ou retorno de função.

> mixed end ( array &$array )

O código deve ficar dessa forma:

```
$nome_do_arquivo_original_alterado = 'teste.png';
$arr = explode('.', $nome_do_arquivo_original_alterado);
$arquivo_renomeado = strtolower(end($arr));
```

Complementando o comentário do gmsantos, a partir do php5.3 `E_STRICT` não pertence a `E_ALL`. Já no php5.4 `E_STRICT` passou a fazer parte de `E_ALL`. Para exibir os erros/warnings `E_STRICT` no php5.3 adicione essas duas linhas no início do script:

```
 ini_set('display_errors', true);
 error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);
```

Comment: Valeu pela ajuda funcionado agora legal ^_^

Comment: Ótima a dica do `&`. Já tinha tido esse problema, mas não sabia em que casos aconteciam.

Comment: @RodrigoRigotti, tem um jeito mais 'esperto' de resolver esse problema, não conhecie ele, está [nessa resposta](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21016338/1342547)

Comment: Obrigada ai pela sua ajuda também serio e fogo esses erros que da tirando que se eu deixar em php 5.3 não da isso.

Comment: Se o erro não aparece no PHP 5.3 é porque esse tipo de erros (Strict Erros está desativado).