# Problema fazendo upload de arquivos

Tags: php, arquivo

Tenho um bloco de código para fazer *upload* de arquivos, porém sempre que tento fazer o *upload* aparece uma mensagem dizendo "Por favor, envie arquivos com as seguintes extensões: jpg, png ou gif". Estou tentando fazer o *upload* de um arquivo `docx` e já especifiquei isso:

```
$_UP['extensoes'] = array('docx', 'xlsx', 'pdf', 'jpg', 'png', 'gif', 'jpeg' );
```

Por que a mensagem aparece mesmo eu tendo "liberado" outras extensões?

```
$extensao = @strtolower(end(explode('.', $_FILES['arquivoJuridico']['name'])));
if (array_search($extensao, $_UP['extensoes']) === false) {
   echo "Por favor, envie arquivos com as seguintes extensões: jpg, png ou gif";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Fiz um teste e funcionou:

```
$_UP['extensoes'] = array('docx', 'xlsx', 'pdf', 'jpg', 'png', 'gif', 'jpeg' );
$extensao = @strtolower(end(explode('.', "nome.doc")));
if (array_search($extensao, $_UP['extensoes']) === false) {
   echo "Por favor, envie arquivos com as seguintes extensões: jpg, png ou gif";
}
$extensao = @strtolower(end(explode('.', "nome.docx")));
if (array_search($extensao, $_UP['extensoes']) === false) {
   echo "Por favor, envie arquivos com as seguintes extensões: jpg, png ou gif";
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/dtcczP). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/@maniero/ExplodeFiles). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/Algorithm/ExplodeFiles.php).

Fora isto você tem algum problema que não é possível identificar pelo que você postou na pergunta. Uma possibilidade é o nome do arquivo não estar vindo corretamente no `$_FILES['arquivoJuridico']['name']`.

Não compare diretamente com `true` ou `false` em um local que espera uma expressão booleana.

Outra coisa, quando você coloca um `@` para executar alguma coisa, provavelmente você sabe que dá um erro. O `@` apenas esconde o erro, não faz a execução ser correta.

Comment: É que se eu não colocar o @ o sistema empaca sem motivo!
Peguei esse código de uma site e ele já veio com essa comparação direta com false.

Comment: Não existe sem motivo em programação. Tem um erro ali. E provavelmente é esse erro que está causado o erro seguinte. O `@` apenas trocou o erro de lugar e deixou mais difícil descobrir a causa. É o que eu falei, a não ser que tenha um motivo muito forte e só quem tem muita experiência sabe identificar um motivo muito forte, o `@` de omissão de erro  **nunca** deveria ser usado. Mande imprimir o conteúdo de `$_FILES['arquivoJuridico']['name']` de preferência com guardas na *string*: `echo "|" . $_FILES['arquivoJuridico']['name'] . "|";` para ver se tem um nome de arquivo ali. E poste o erro.

Comment: $extensao = @strtolower(end(explode('.', $_FILES['arquivoJuridico']['name'])));
          if (array_search($extensao, $_UP['extensoes']) === false) {
          echo "Por favor, envie arquivos com as seguintes extensões: jpg, png ou gif";
          }


Quando tiro o @:
Strict standards: Only variables should be passed by reference in C:\Program Files (x86)\VertrigoServ\www\marco\php\reclamatorias\zanellaP1.php on line 700

Strict standards: Only variables should be passed by reference in C:\Program Files (x86)\VertrigoServ\www\marco\php\reclamatorias\zanellaP1.php on line 700

Comment: Edite sua pergunta para colocar informações adicionais.

Comment: @GustavoSevero, O erro da `@` é facil de arrumar, basta você pegar o retorno do `explode` e jogar em uma variável e depois chamar `strtolower() e end()`. Assim:
`$arr = explode('.', $_FILES['arquivoJuridico']['name']);$extensao = strtolower(end($arr));`
[mais detalhes nessa pergunta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/45931/91)

Comment: Assim?

$extensao = strtolower(end(explode('.', $_FILES['arquivoJuridico']['name'])));
          $arr = explode('.', $_FILES['arquivoJuridico']['name']);
          $extensao = strtolower(end($arr));

Comment: @rray Eu estou tentando reproduzir o erro e não consigo. http://ideone.com/IqWiW6. É exatamente o seu código a única coisa que fiz diferente é inicializar o `$FILES` na mão já que não posso receber os dados de fora e mesmo que pudesse, seria difícil reproduzir exatamente a mesma situação. Eu acredito que seu problema não é de código e sim de ambiente.

Comment: @bigown, você pode simular o `Strict Standards...` no ideon adicionando 2 linhas no inicio, sei la parece que ele tem alguma configuração para não exibir warnings, [exemplo com warnings](http://ideone.com/rOwtFk)

Comment: Simular o Strict Standards?

Comment: Descobri o meu problema... Estava esquecendo do "enctype="multipart/form-data"

Comment: Conforme eu estava dizendo o problema não está nesse código apresentado.